# How to change the image every time when I launch a single fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity. In that when I launch a single fragment, i should get different image for each launch of fragment.

```
  public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
           //     mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
             //   mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
               //`enter code here` mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you use Android Studio but you have to be more specific with how you want to determine the image if you want to determine it based on integer sent to fragment try this

```
public static class CustomFragment extends Fragment{
.....
@Override
public void onCreateView()
{
    position = getArguments().getInt("ARG_SECTION_NUMBER")
    View view = getView(getActivity());
    return view;
}

public View getView(context)
{
    View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.view_layout,null);
    ImageView image= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    switch(position)
    {
        case(1):
        image.setImageResource(your_image_res_for_1);
            break;
        .....
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

}

or if you want to determine based on something else use an if statement or even switch depending on what it is you are using to determine.....hope i helped